# NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am getting the below error in Windows 10 even though I have configured JAVA_HOME to the correct directory I believe. I know that there are similar questions but none of them seem to have a clear resolution for resolving this on windows 10.

Error:

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

JAVA_HOME Variable: 
[image]
Contents of JDK Folder:
[image]

Verifying variable in CMD:

[image]

Comment: You have a ``\\`` before the `:` in `C:\Program Files`

Comment: Hint: when using strings that mean a path, you can always take that string into a command line shell and check if it is really valid. Your path is obviously broken.

Comment: Corrected the root directory to C:\ (which I am sure I had correct in my initial attempts). I am still getting the same error. Also verified variable via CMD.

Comment: Try logging off or rebooting. Also try unsetting all JAVA_HOME at system and user level.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the bin directory in your jdk home directory.  The bin folder is where all the good stuff is like the compiler and much more.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was suspicious. I had originally downloaded Java SE 10.0.01 but just tried Java SE 8U172 which contained the bin directory and worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had originally downloaded Java SE 10.0.01 which for some reason did not contain a bin directory. Just tried Java SE 8U172 which contained the bin directory and worked.

Answer (score -1):

You can try setting system 'Path' variable with \bin added like this "%JAVA_HOME%\bin". Or edit the JAVA_HOME variable to include \bin.

Comment: No, just no....